# Browser and Mail windows get smaller just by themselves

Tags: mail.app, mouse, monterey, apple-silicon, web-browser

On a new MacBook Pro M1 running Monterey. Quite often, when I move my mouse toward some windows on max size (not full screen) such as the browser (Firefox) or the Mail app, the window suddenly gets smaller just by itself. It happens several times a day and it's going on since a couple of months.

How do I stop it?

Comment: What is the model / year of your Mac? How long have you been facing this issue? Have you had a chance to check whether this happens with a different mouse?

Comment: edited to include those details. I haven't tried with a different mouse yet.

Comment: Did you turn on Hot Corners for Mission Control and have one set for Expose?

Comment: I only have one hot corner for Desktop.